# How to clear histograms in subplots of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to page through a series of histograms on a single figure. Ultimately, I will have a button that will let me move forwqards or backwards through the series. But, for now, I am unable to clear the present histogram in order to make way for the next one.

My basic approach is as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.hist(hist1)
fig.show() # This successfully displays my histogram
ax.clear()
fig.show() # The histogram is still present. Clearing was ineffective.
```

How can I clear the axes, so that the figure will be ready for the next histogram?

---

A Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example:

```
me@home:~/Projects/kerasECOC$ python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.randn(100)
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
>>> ax.hist(a)
(array([ 7.,  4., 16., 11., 15., 16., 17.,  8.,  3.,  3.]), array([-1.96828374, -1.54116206, -1.11404039, -0.68691871, -0.25979703,
        0.16732464,  0.59444632,  1.02156799,  1.44868967,  1.87581134,
        2.30293302]), <a list of 10 Patch objects>)
>>> fig.show()
>>> ax.clear()
>>> fig.show() #Figure is unchanged. I expected a blank fig as in ImportanceOfBeingErnest's example
>>> plt.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'2.2.2'
>>>
```

Comment: IIUC try `fig.clf()` instead of `ax.clear`.

Comment: `ax.clear()` will clear the axes. Your code also runs fine for me. Maybe you want to go into more details about how and where you run it, provide information about your system, versions etc.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I've just added some more detail

Comment: I still cannot reproduce. After running the code I get a cleared axes, as seen [in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5ErT.png). Of course I don't know what you have in `examine_weights.py`, that's why [mcve]s are so important.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I'm sorry. You're right about minimal, complete and verifiable. I should've created a test like yours. Oddly, I transferred my code to a different machine and I now see the behaviour I expected. If rebooting the original machine doesn't work, I'm going to have to see if changing various versions does the trick.